# Unable to save my files with Storage::put($file, $content) in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-5

Just a simple doubts-

i'm trying to store my image and video file on storage using Storage facade.
but i'm confused because i'm unable to store that file on storage folder.
i'm using intervention image package and when i just try to save my modified $file

`Storage::put($file);`
it's throwing error that 2 argument missing etc.

i searched everywhere on the net regarding this issue and i found

`Storage::put($file , $content)`
now what is $content in this case when i'm trying just save an image to my folder ? please give me example-

and one more thing

How do i return a full path of that file which can be accessible from different domain.
i'm building an API :)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem `put(filename, contents)`

Comment: There is an example for saving a binary file in the documentation Mike B linked (search for avatar).

Comment: i did already, but still confused that what exactly $content is in Storage::put('file.jpg' , $content); :(

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter in `Storage::put($filename, $content)` refers to the raw information that makes up the file. For a text file, `$content` would be the text, while for an image, it'd be the raw information that makes up the image.

Since you're using Intervention Image, you can use the [`encode()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) method to get the data needed for storage.

```
// Assuming that $file is your Intervention Image instance
// Example 1: Save as the default type (JPEG)
Storage::put('public/images/my_profile.jpeg', $file->encode());

// Example 2: Save as a PNG
Storage::put('public/images/my_profile.png', $file->encode('png'));
```

In regards to your question about how to refer to that path as a URL, make sure to follow the following snippet from the documentation:

> Note: When using the local driver, be sure to create a symbolic link at public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory.

After that, you'll be able to access everything from `storage/app/public` from the browser like such:

```
echo config('app.url') . str_replace('/public/', '/', Storage::url('public/images/my_profile.png'));
// Echoes "http://localhost/storage/images/my_profile.png"
```

Comment: I tried this one too, but there is i'm getting an error with ```$image->encode()```  error - ```Call to a member function encode() on string``` i have already got what i wanted by simon answer this will be a great bonus :)

Comment: @Rahul I had assumed that your instance of Intervention Image was `$image`; after re-reading your question, is `$file` your Intervention Image instance? If so, replace `$image` with `$file`

Comment: Chris , now it's working great, Thank you so much for your help too, appreciate your time :)

Comment: One more this Chris , i'm building an API , so how can i return full url of saved image file from storage and access it via angular on different domain , i'm using laravel CORS already. ?

Comment: Yes Chris, thank you so much - im just working on that..i'm using local disk- and homestead for server... well i'm little confused.. i'm little new to laravel , so could you please show me how to create that symbolic link in public/storage or you can redirect somewhere which can help me on that. you are an angel for me today :)

Answer (score 5):

What disk your using 'public', 'local' basically where your storing it?

```
   \Storage::disk('local')->put($file_name, $the_file);
```

The disk settings can be view in the `config/filesystems.php` file.

Also the `$content` is the actually item/file you want to save. Here is an example of what ive done recently..

```
   // the $image is from $request->file('file');
   $thefile = \File::get($image);
   $file_name = $title->slug . '-' . $year . '.jpg';
    \Storage::disk('local')->put($file_name, $thefile);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you soooo much simon, it's just work like charm.. SO thankful for your time. :)